# Rails4: undefined method `committed? for Model Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Rails 4 application and recently got into a strange issue. I am looking for your help here. Kindly advise.

A small gist snippet has been created to understand the issue [undefined method committed?](https://gist.github.com/puneetpandey/bafd8d78087d8713da79)

Just to summarize everything:

```
# app/models
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :report
  has_many :points
  belongs_to :user
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :response
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :response
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :responses do
    resources :action_plans
  end
end

# app/controllers/action_plans_controller.rb
class ActionPlansController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :response

  def new
    @report = @response.build_report
    5.times do
      @response.points.build
    end
  end

private
  def response
    @response = current_user.responses.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Whenever, I am trying to hit:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/:user_id/responses/:id/action_plans/new
```

I get error that says: undefined method `committed?' for Response Object. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: please provide the trace for the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By defining a method called `response` in your controller you're overriding an internal getter used by Rails. To solve the problem, just use a different name for your before action. The common way of naming the action is to use `set_<entity name>` so `set_response` it is.

Comment: OMG!! that worked! Unknowingly, I was actually overriding getter method of Rails. BTW, thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Response class namespaced inside ActionDispatch (ActionDispatch::Response) and it is used throughout Rails. Can it be the case that you're actually hitting the response object instead of your model? Maybe use [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) to debug it from inside?

Comment: What I got so far is, that I was using the wrong method name in before_filter. But what I don't understand is, the error, that says: undefined method? committed?. What committed?, signifies here?